# SQL Server CE 4.0 select consecutive numeric field

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-ce

I am back trying to get this to work (after a couple years). It's for SQL Server CE 4.0.

Below is some test script that anyone can copy and run to test.

The `@Keyword` table would be what the user inputs.

These would be the song ID's. Each show has song ID's and a SongOrder column.

`SongOrder` must be consecutive.

To test this, change the order of `@Keywords` and the `ShowId` remains and it should not.

Must find a show with that particular song list in that particular order.

So, the user is looking for a show(s) with that particular song order.

Each TABLE param created in the test script mirrors the actual database.

The `SELECT` should only return 1546 but it's not playing nice.

```
--Test two shows, years apart
DECLARE @Shows TABLE (ID INT)

INSERT INTO @Shows (ID) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @Shows (ID) VALUES (1546)

--Add a few songs
DECLARE @Songs TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(256))

INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'Song 1')
INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (2, 'Song 2')
INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (3, 'Song 3')
INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (654, 'Song 4')
INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (321, 'Song 5')
INSERT INTO @Songs (ID, Name) VALUES (322, 'Song 6')

--Where the shows and songs get their reference
DECLARE @ShowSongRef TABLE (ID INT, ShowID INT, SongID INT, SongOrder INT, PRIMARY KEY (ID))

--Show 1
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (2, 1, 2, 2)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (3, 1, 321, 3)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (4, 1, 3, 4)
--Show 1546
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (5, 1546, 3, 1)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (6, 1546, 1, 2)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (7, 1546, 654, 3)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (8, 1546, 321, 4)
INSERT INTO @ShowSongRef (ID, ShowID, SongID, SongOrder) VALUES (9, 1546, 322, 5)

--The song order we are looking for
--Doesn't matter where in the show the order occurs
DECLARE @Keyword TABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @Keyword (ID) VALUES ('654')
INSERT INTO @Keyword (ID) VALUES ('321')
INSERT INTO @Keyword (ID) VALUES ('322')

--This should only return 1546
SELECT DISTINCT sh.ID AS ShowID--, s.Name 
FROM @Songs s
INNER JOIN @ShowSongRef ref ON ref.SongID = s.ID

--Comment out this join or remove the +1 and it works but in any order
INNER JOIN @ShowSongRef ref2 ON ref2.SongID = s.ID
        AND ref2.SongOrder = ref.SongOrder + 1 --remove the +1 and it works but are they in order? Not always
        AND ref2.ShowID = ref.ShowID

INNER JOIN @Shows sh ON sh.ID = ref.ShowID
WHERE ref.SongID IN (SELECT ID FROM @Keyword)

GROUP BY sh.ID
HAVING COUNT(sh.ID) = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @Keyword)
--ORDER BY ref2.SongOrder

--Couldn't get this to work either
--SELECT 
--  ShowID
--FROM
--  @ShowSongRef m
--CROSS JOIN
--   (SELECT COUNT(ID) AS consec FROM @Keyword) x
--WHERE 
--  EXISTS
--     (SELECT 1 FROM @ShowSongRef ref
--          INNER JOIN @Shows sh ON sh.ID = ref.ShowID
--          WHERE ref.SongID IN (SELECT ID FROM @Keyword)
--          AND ref.SongOrder = m.SongOrder - x.consec + 1
--          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
  showsong.ShowID, Showsong.SongId, showsong.SongOrder, song.*
FROM   @Shows       AS show
JOIN   @ShowSongRef AS showsong ON show.ID         = showsong.ShowID
JOIN   @Songs       AS song     ON showsong.SongID = song.ID
JOIN   @Keyword     AS kw       ON song.ID         = kw.ID
ORDER BY -COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY showsong.ShowID);
```

or, if you can't use Window Aggregate functions (e.g. `COUNT(*) OVER...` then:

```
WITH correctId AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (1) ShowID
  FROM
  (
    SELECT showsong.ShowID, ttl = COUNT(*)
    FROM   @Shows       AS show
    JOIN   @ShowSongRef AS showsong ON show.ID         = showsong.ShowID
    JOIN   @Songs       AS song     ON showsong.SongID = song.ID
    JOIN   @Keyword     AS kw       ON song.ID         = kw.ID
    GROUP BY showsong.ShowID
  ) AS x
  ORDER BY -ttl
)
SELECT     
  showsong.ShowID, Showsong.SongId, showsong.SongOrder, song.*
FROM       @Shows       AS show
JOIN       @ShowSongRef AS showsong ON show.ID         = showsong.ShowID
JOIN       @Songs       AS song     ON showsong.SongID = song.ID
JOIN       @Keyword     AS kw       ON song.ID         = kw.ID
CROSS JOIN correctId
WHERE      showsong.ShowID = (SELECT showId FROM correctId);
```

**ORIGINAL:**

Something like this perhaps:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES *,
  -- if this number does not chnage then the song order is consecutive
  Songordercheck = showsong.songorder - 
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY show.ID ORDER BY showsong.songorder)
FROM   @Shows       AS show
JOIN   @ShowSongRef AS showsong ON show.ID         = showsong.ShowID
JOIN   @Songs       AS song     ON showsong.SongID = song.ID
JOIN   @Keyword     AS kw       ON song.ID         = kw.ID
ORDER BY -COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY show.ID)
```

Comment: If I wasn't using SQLCe then I wouldn't have this issue. SQLCe does not support ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: I just edited my answer... Let me know if that helps